# React NextJS Pass an object as a prop based on a string value from state

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx, react-props

I would like to dynamically pass an Object down as a prop based on a string that changes with state.

Explanation by way of example:

```js
// ================== PARENT ===============================
import truck from '../images/truck.webp'
import car from '../images/car.webp'
import bus from '../images/bus.webp'

export default function Index() {
const [ type, setType ] = useState('') 

  setType('truck')// <=== changes based on user doing something.

  let typeElement = []
  if (type) {
    typeElement = 
    <Type
      key={type}
      image={type} // <=== I would like to dynamically pass the object by string in state
      type={type}/>
  }

return (
     <>
         {typeElement}
     </>
)}

//============== CHILD =================
import Image from 'next/image'

function Type(props) {
const { image, type } = props

return (
     <>
       <p>I am a picture of a {type}</p>
       <Image src={image}>
    </>
)
}
```

The above line `image={type}` does not work.
For this code to work I must pass the object 'truck, car, bus, etc' down as a prop.

`image={truck}`

But I want to reference the imported object via the string name in state.

Any ideas?

I have tried many ways to call the object based on it's name in state but I am unsuccessful.

Comment: Are you giving the image source in the child component, a `string` instead of a `url` or an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
// ================== PARENT ===============================
import truck from '../images/truck.webp'
import car from '../images/car.webp'
import bus from '../images/bus.webp'

const types = {
  truck: truck,
  car: car,
  bus: bus,
}

export default function Index() {
  const [ type, setType ] = useState('')

  setType('truck') // <=== changes based on user doing something.

  let typeElement = []
  if (type) {
    typeElement = (
      <Type
        key={type}
        image={types[type]} // <=== Dynamically pass the object by string in state
        type={type}
      />
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      {typeElement}
    </>
  )
}

//============== CHILD =================
import Image from 'next/image'

function Type(props) {
  const { image, type } = props

  return (
    <>
      <p>I am a picture of a {type}</p>
      <Image src={image} />
    </>
  )
}
```